# iPhone 6 plus design resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, iphone-6-plus

The `iPhone 6 plus` has a res of `1920x1080` but that is down scaled from virtual res of `2208x1242`

My questions is , are the designs(in Photoshop) suppose to be made in `1920x1080` or `2208x1242` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2208x1242` with an `@3x` file extension

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to be in 1242x2208 for Photoshop for the iPhone 6 Plus in Portrait. 1242 being the width (in pixels) and 2208 being the height (in pixels). The file extension should be @3x.

Answer (score 1):

Use 2208x1242 if that is what is being down scaled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes @3x for file extntion.
eg: ic_back@3x.png

I recommended to refer apple website [Check here](https://www.apple.com/iphone-6/display/)

and you can also use 960x1704 screen resolution for portrait mode or 1242x2208